# Total internal reflection in fiber optics cables

Tags: fiber

The total internal reflection occurs when the angle of incidence is greater than the critical angle,then why is there a need of high refractive index of the core and low refractive index of the cladding?
[image]

Comment: i'm not entirely sure physics falls under superuser... ;p

Comment: thats what Super means lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The higher the difference between the refractive indices of the media at the interface, the steeper the critical angle.

Comment: not depending upon which refractive index is higher and which is lower?

Comment: The critical angle only exists from the higher index to the lower index.